# SASS Preset variables in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, sass

I have a Symfony2 project with SASS & Compass(without Leafo Sass can't use Leafo because it doesn't support Compass 100%) and I would like to send some variables from config.yml to a SASS file like the presets used by Leafo Less

```
 presets:
     my_variable: "#000"
```

Is something like that possible using SASS(without leafo sass)? The variable has to be in config.yml or similar because the code is reused accross a couple of sites but each one should have their own variables, for this reason sass variables inside .scss files can't be used

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. While compass/sass compile files after each change, how would they even know you use Symfony? Probably you could make some extra script/class but you should run it always before compilation of sass files and it wouldn't have much sense. That's my opinion however I'm not expert neither in Compass/Sass nor in Symfony2.